# Can't get Rails, MAMP, mysql2 to work together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mamp, mysql2

I'm currently trying to get the following to work together, to no avail:

Rails 3.1.1
MAMP 2.0.2
mysql2 5.5.9
Ruby 1.9.2
Mac OSX 10.7 (lion)

Everything appears installed.. mysql2 and rails show up in my gem list.  I used the instructions found here to install mysql2 and it seemed to go smoothly:

http://blog.mirotin.net/35/mamp-1-9-5-mysql-5-5-9-and-ruby-mysql2

I've also specified the MAMP socket in my database.yml file:  socket: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

My rails application runs fine with sqlite3, but when I change database to mysql2 and try to run webrick, I get a generic ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished) message.

What am I missing?

Comment: Not really an answer, just an alternative: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book Read the first chapter It's a free book. It'll help you setup ruby with rvm, git, rails server, sqlite and push to heroku for production.

Answer (score 0):

You have to downgrade to mysql 5.1. I had the same problem. Then you need to install the mysql2 gem with the following command:

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Also, you may want to try replacing `gem 'mysql2'` with `gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'`

Comment: I just downgraded to mysql2 0.2.7 using the following: sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install --version '0.2.7' mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config

How do I know which gem version is being used now, as I have 0.3.7 and 0.2.7 installed?

Also, how do I downgrade to mysql 5.1?  Thanks

Comment: You need to speicfy it in your Gemfile. To downgrade to 5.1, you will need to uninstall 5.5 and then download the DMG from the mysql website. Information on how to remove 5.5 can be found at this link: http://www.brianbruijn.com/?q=node/24. Also, you should consider switching to RVM to manage your ruby versions, it is very nice.

Comment: thanks... and I do use rvm, good stuff.  Won't those instructions remove mysql from the mac os?  I'm using MAMP, which has it's own version of mysql, no?

Comment: Yea haha I guess you are right. Hmm, I don't know then. Sorry!